# Is it possible to implement Webpack HMR for Polymer components?

Tags: javascript, webpack, polymer

Would it be technically possible to implement a loader for Webpack that takes advantage of [HMR](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html) to use with Polymer that preserves application state, like the one implemented for [React](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr), VueJS (github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) or Angular (github.com/yargalot/Angular-HMR)?

It would help a lot during development not to reload the whole application when you make changes a file in a polymer component.

Comment: This might solve the issue.

https://github.com/aruntk/wc-loader. 

Demo https://github.com/aruntk/polymer-webpack-demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no easy way to do Webpack based hot reloading of Polymer elements.
This is due to the fact that web-components/Polymer import dependencies differently (using HTML imports) compared to the Webpack based stacks (using ES2015 modules and loaders). See also this [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/547).
There are efforts tough to implement the HTML imports using ES2015 modules once the spec is finalized (this might take some time tough).

If you use [redux](http://redux.js.org/) for application state management, and keep your Polymer elements as stateless as possible, you could at least suse HMR for your `reducers` which help during development.
For combining webpack + polymer you could check out [this](https://github.com/dannykruitbosch/polymer-redux-webpack) or [this](https://github.com/home-assistant/home-assistant-polymer) repo.